# How to force a priority on QProcess

Tags: linux, qt, qprocess

I do not see any API to set the priority of a `QProcess` in Qt Documentation. I assume the process is started with normal priority.

Is there a way to start the process with lower priority on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there exists an API to set the priority of the process using a Qt call. I used direct Linux calls and was successfully able to change the process priority.
Refer : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/setpriority.html

Answer (score 3):

Overload `QProcess::setupChildProcess()` and write something about:

```
void QtvProcess::setupChildProcess()
{
#if defined Q_OS_UNIX
    if (::nice(5) == -1) // default: +5
        perror("nice");
#endif
}
```